# How to get next 50 rows from archive.org API

Tags: api

i am using archive.org get audio books, now i want load next 50 results how i can do that? my current connection URL is here, its retrieve only first 50 results

```
val LIBRIVOX_URL = "https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=subject%3A%22librivox%22+AND+mediatype%3Aaudio&fl[]=avg_rating&fl[]=publisher&fl[]=description&fl[]=downloads&fl[]=identifier&fl[]=mediatype&fl[]=num_reviews&fl[]=title&sort[]=&sort[]=&sort[]=&rows=50&page=1&output=json&callback=callback&save=yes"
```

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this will help you out, you can use your url to select the number of rows you want back in your result, for example: http://localhost:9000/100 'will return 100 results'

Here is the code:

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    let rows = req.params.id;
    let mediatype = 'audio';
    let archiveUrl = `https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=subject%3A%22librivox%22+AND+mediatype%3A${mediatype}&fl[]=avg_rating&fl[]=publisher&fl[]=description&fl[]=downloads&fl[]=identifier&fl[]=mediatype&fl[]=num_reviews&fl[]=title&sort[]=&sort[]=&sort[]=&rows=${rows}&page=1&output=json`
    axios.get(archiveUrl)
    .then(elem => {
        res.json(elem.data.response.docs);
    })
})
```